# Any idea why this code doesn't work as intended?

Tags: python

This is my first python code. The code is supposed to prompt user with options and then perform actions based on the user input.

However, when I run the code, instead of prompting for the menu I get the prompt to enter the movie title. Here's the code I have written so far.

```
# code starts here

MENU_PROMPT = "\nEnter 'a' to add a movie, 'l' to see your movies, 'f' to find your movie or 'q' to quit: "

movies = []


def add_movie():
    title = input("Enter the movie title: ")
    director = input("Enter the movie director: ")
    year = input("Enter the movie year: ")

    movies.append({
        'title': title,
        'director': director,
        'year': year
    })


def show_movies():
    for movie in movies:
        print_movie(movie)


def print_movie(movie):
    print(f"Title : {movie['title']}")
    print(f"Director : {movie['director']}")
    print(f"Release Year : {movie['year']}")


def find_movie():
    search_title = input("Enter movie title you are looking for: ")

    for movie in movies:
        if movie["title"] == search_title:
            print_movie(movie)


user_options =  {
    "a" : add_movie(),
    "l" : show_movies(),
    "f" : find_movie()
}

def menu():
    selection = input(MENU_PROMPT)
    while selection != "q":
        if selection in user_options:
            selected_function = user_options[selection]
            selected_function()
        else:
            print('Unknown command, Please try again')

        selection = input(MENU_PROMPT)

menu()


#code ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a dictionary with a value being a function, it will run that function to fill in the value of the dictionary. So that is why it is running `add_movie()` first before anything else.

The proper way to do your menu would be like this:

```py
>>> def x():
...     print("hi")
... 
>>> y = {'a':x}
>>> y['a']()
hi
```

We save the value of the dictionary as the function name, then call it by adding the `()` to the returned value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is greatly appreciated.